# Connect a Rails application to microsoft access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ms-access

I have a client which want to have data from a form to an access database. I seen some odbc connector for rails but it's only old projects.

I can export/inport data in CSV but I want the simpler solution.

Do you know if there is a solution to connect Rails with Access?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If his access database doesnt already exist then a good solution would be to create a rails application with a MySQL database then use microsoft access as a front end to the mysql db (OBDC). Ref [Access as front end to MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access.html#connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-linked-tables)

So he can see all data from the mysql db through access and easily import the entire db to his local machine if he wanted to but it wouldn't be required.